# Bash if else compare num1 with num2 or num3 does not compare correctly

Tags: bash, if-statement, scripting, compare

I'm a newby on bash scripting and need help.

I've made script that needs to compare a user input (fixed choices for 045, 046, 287 or 279). With other values.

When the user inputs 045 or 046 then the if statement is true and should display

*You have choosen $SID. Menu 1 will be used*

If the user inputs 287 or 279 the statement need to false and display

*You have choosen $SID. Menu 2 will be used*

$SID is the user input given above.

```
  if [ "$SID" == "046" -o "045" ] ; then
        printf "You have choosen $SID. Menu 1 will be used" 
        else 
        printf "You have choosen $SID. Menu 2 will be used"
  fi
```

But when running the script it always displays the true statement with the users input displayed on the $SID location.

```
You have choosen 045. Menu 1 will be used
You have choosen 046. Menu 1 will be used
You have choosen 287. Menu 1 will be used
You have choosen 279. Menu 1 will be used
```

What I would expect is this:

When 045 or 046 is used:

```
You have choosen 045. Menu 1 will be used
You have choosen 046. Menu 1 will be used
```

When 279 or 287 is used:

```
You have choosen 287. Menu 2 will be used
You have choosen 279. Menu 2 will be used
```

I also tried the following if statement without results:

```
  if [ $SID -eq 046 -o 045 ] ; then

  if [ "$SID" -eq "046" -o "045" ] ; then

  if [ $SID = 046 -o 045 ] ; then

  if [ "$SID" = "046" -o "045" ] ; then
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `[ "$SID" == "046" -o "$SID" == "045" ]` this is the correct syntax

Comment: it's `(expr) -o (expr)`, not `operand operator (operand -o operand)` ; in your case the `045` was considered true, so the condition was always true since `x -o true` = true

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I've been breaking my head on this the last couple of days. It works perfectly now!

Comment: Note that inside `[ ]`, you should use `=` instead of `==` (bash understands both, but not all other shells do; and if you're counting on bash, you might as well use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`). Also, note that `=` (and `==`) in this context do string comparison, so if the user enters "45", that's not equal to "045". Inside `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`, use `-eq` for numeric comparison. Actually, "045" isn't considered equal numerically equal to "45" either, since the shell assumes numbers that start with "0" are octal, so "045" is numerically equal to "37". Yes, this is complicated.

Comment: Best to assume 045 and 046 are simply string literals without any real numerical connotation.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds several problems with the example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-o` joins expressions, not multiple values in a single expression.

```
if [ "$SID" = 046 -o "$SID" = 045 ] ; then
```

However, `-o` itself shouldn't be used; it is considered obsolete and not guaranteed to be supported by a POSIX-compliant shell. Use `||` to join two separate `[` commands instead.

```
if [ "$SID" = 046 ] || [ "$SID" = 045 ] ; then
```

A `case` statement may be more concise:

```
case $SID in
  045|046) printf 'You have chosen %s. Menu 1 will be used\n' "$SID" ;;
  *)       printf 'You have chosen %s. Menu 2 will be used\n' "$SID" ;;
esac
```

which would immediately suggest (highlighted by my use of whitespace) a refactoring of

```
case $SID in
  045|046) menu=1 ;;
  *) menu=2 ;;
esac

printf 'You have chosen %s. Menu %s will be used\n' "$SID" "$menu"
```

Given that you are actually using `bash`, you might choose to use the `[[` command instead of `[`, which allows `case`-style pattern matching:

```
if [[ $SID = 04[56] ]]; then
```

Comment: You don't need `extglob` in this case.  `04[56]` is an equivalent glob pattern.

Comment: Ugh. You know, I felt like I was overthinking that.